# Overlay Image at specific point (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

I have a certain point on an image. I understand you can overlay function with the addWeighted method, but to my knowledge there is no way to do that with a specific point. Essentially I want to overlay the image with the center of the image being that specific point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please try to be clearer about what you want to do. Do you just want to add one point? What have the aruco markers got to do with it?

Comment: such things have been asked countless times. granted, it's hard to search for because everyone has different words for the same thing. -- use numpy slicing to insert the smaller picture into the larger one.

Comment: If you want to do blending with the insert, then insert your image into second image using Numpy slicing, then apply addWeighted between the inserted first image result and the second image.

Comment: If your chosen spot is close to the edge, what are you going to fill the rest of the places with? If you want to take a section from the image, you can copy pixel values according to a specific offset value, it is already of type CV2 nd.array.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks.